# I'm having an issue running npx

Tags: node.js, npm

I do have node.js downloaded but I get the following error when I try to run it lynne@DESKTOP-QRM1JIT MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Documents/CIS117/labs (feature/environment-setup)

```
$  npx create-react-app bidpro-admin
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\lynne\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\lynne\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\lynne\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-17T18_18_04_994Z-debug-0.log
```